# Campo EdiText, colocarlo invisible

Tags: c#, xamarin

estoy intentado colocar campo tipo EdiText, con dato String en invisible pero no he podido. no me funcionado

```
MSJTEnvioExitoso.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
```

ni tampoco

```
MSJTEnvioExitoso.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

este es el código:

```
 using System;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.Content;
    using Java.IO;
    using Android.Provider;
    using System.IO;
    using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;




    namespace LoginSystem
    {
    public class OnAutorizacionEventArgs
    {
        public string mTxtCedula;
        public string mTxtFirstName;
        public string mTxtFirst;
        public string mTxtEmail;
        public string mTxtCelular;
        public string mTxtTelefono;

        public string Cedula

        {
            get { return mTxtCedula; }
            set { mTxtCedula = value; }
        }
        public string Nombre

        {
            get { return mTxtFirstName; }
            set { mTxtFirstName = value; }
        }
        public string Apellido

        {
            get { return mTxtFirst; }
            set { mTxtFirst = value; }
        }

        public string Email

        {
            get { return mTxtEmail; }
            set { mTxtEmail = value; }
        }
        public string Celular

        {
            get { return mTxtCelular; }
            set { mTxtCelular = value; }
        }
        public string Telefono

        {
            get { return mTxtTelefono; }
            set { mTxtTelefono = value; }
        }


        public void Dialog_Autorizacion() { }
        public void SDialog_Autorizacion(string cedula, string nombre, string email, string telefono, string celular)

        {
            this.Cedula = celular;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Celular = celular;
            this.Telefono = telefono;


        }
        public OnAutorizacionEventArgs(string cedula, string nombre, string email, string telefono, string celular)
        {
            this.Cedula = celular;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Celular = celular;
            this.Telefono = telefono;
        }
    }
     public class Autorizacion : DialogFragment
    {
        private string MSJTOMARgaleria = "Por favor reucuerda tomar primero la foto de la Autorizacion";
        private string MSJTEnvioExitoso = "Tu solicitud Esta En proceso, muy pronto te dare una respuesta";
        private string mTxtInstitucion;
        private string mTxtCedula;
        private string mTxtNombre;
        private string mTxtCiudad;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private Button Adjuntar;
        private Button Enviar;
        private View textView;
        System.String uris;
        private string mTxtNota;


        public Autorizacion(string mTxtNombre, string mTxtCedula)
        {
            this.mTxtNombre = mTxtNombre;
            this.mTxtCedula = mTxtCedula;

        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            textView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Autorizaciones, container, false);
            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoNombre).Text = mTxtNombre;
            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCedula).Text = mTxtCedula;
            textView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtNota).Text = MSJTOMARgaleria;
            MSJTEnvioExitoso.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;




            imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);

            Adjuntar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamara);
            Enviar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEnviar);
            Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;


            Adjuntar.Click += delegate
            {
                var imageIntent = new Intent();
                imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
                imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
                mTxtInstitucion = textView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAutoInstitucion).Text;
                mTxtCiudad = textView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCiudad).Text;




            };


            Enviar.Click += delegate 
            {
                try
                {
                    //Configurando el cliente SMTP
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
                    {
                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        Port = 587,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com", "jwspvnzutniimvkm")
                    };
                    //Preparando archivo adjunto
                    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uris, "");
                    var File = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                    var path = Uri.FromFile(File);

                    //Enviando correo
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
                    {
                        From = new MailAddress("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com")
                    };
                    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com"));
                    mail.Subject = "Solicitud Autorizacion Medica "+mTxtNombre+ " " + mTxtCedula;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Body = "Hola Solicito por favor autorizar procedimiento, adjunto anexo solicitud Medica especificaciones el nombre de la Institución es  "+mTxtInstitucion+
                    " , ciudad "+mTxtCiudad +" ,Nombre de usuario " +mTxtNombre+" y Cedula "+ mTxtCedula+
                    " "+"Gracias por su atención"
                    ;
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(File .Path));
                    client.Send(mail);
                    textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNota).Text = MSJTEnvioExitoso;
                    Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                    imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;




                }
                catch (Exception ex)

                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Mensaje Fallido" , ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            };

            return textView;

        }

        public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);
                imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);
                imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                uris = GetPathToImage(data.Data);
                Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


            }
        }

        private string GetPathToImage(Uri uri )
        {
            string doc_id = "";
            using (var c1 = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
            {
                c1.MoveToFirst();
                System.String document_id = c1.GetString(0);
                doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
            }
            string path = null;

            string selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
            using (var cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
            {
                if (cursor == null) return path;
                var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
            }
            return path;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer invisible esta vista, sería de esta forma usando [**ViewStates.Gone**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone/):

```
MSJTEnvioExitoso.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone
```

---

> **Gone**: elimina el elemento completamente del árbol de objetos.